# splitting data for machine learning

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe that includes texts and i want to split the data according to the "writer" column for the machine learning process. For example, I want to train with texts from Aeschylus and Sophocles and test with the texts from Euripides. How can I do that? I am using sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt your code according to this:

```
authors = ["Aesch", "Soph", "Euri", "Aesch", "Soph", "Euri"]
df = pd.DataFrame(authors, columns=["author"])
df["text"] = ["abc", "bcd", "cde", "abc", "bcd", "cde"]

# split your dataframe with a condition
train = df[df.author!="Euri"]
test = df[df.author=="Euri"]
```

Answer (score -1):

That's what GroupKFold is for, it takes the group column additionally to features and target:

```
group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = group_kfold.split(X, y, group)
```

See documentation here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold

Comment: This seems like a wrong approach. GroupKFold will not achieve what OP is asking for.

Comment: @petezurich I'm pretty sure it will, edited the answer for more clarity. Unless you take that the "for example" is exact specification, and not a generic request to split different authors into different groups (if that's the case, then your answer is correct).

Comment: OP wants to train on two group values and test on another. He doesn't ask for crossvalidation with non-overlapping groups – which is what GroupKFold does.

Comment: And your code doesn't work. The `split` function yields a generator and not 4 splitted data sets.